# Recursive function SQL dosent work and return null value

Tags: sql, sql-server

Trying to build tree menu from SQL:

```
DepID   Name   ParentID  HaveParent
1       dep1     NULL         0
2       dep2     NULL         0
3       dep3      2           1
4       dep4      3           1
5       dep5      4           1



Declare @str nvarchar(MAX);
DECLARE @ID as integer = (select DepartmentID  from tbl_Department  where  ParentID = 2);
IF (@ID > 0)
         BEGIN
              SET @str = '<ul class="navbar-mobile-sub__list list-unstyled js-sub-list">' +  
                         STUFF((SELECT distinct '<li> <a href="OrganizationHierarchy.aspx?ID='
                               + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(max), DepartmentID)
                               +'">'
                               + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(max), DepartmentName) 
                               +'</a>'
                               + dbo.GetDep((select DepartmentID  
                                             from tbl_Department  
                                             where  ParentID= @ID))
                               +'</li>'    
                               from tbl_Department  
                               where  IsHaveParent = 1 AND ParentID = 2 
                               FOR xml path('')), 1 , 1, '') 
                        + '</ul>'
         END
ELSE 
        BEGIN
            SET @str  = '<ul class="navbar-mobile-sub__list list-unstyled js-sub-list">' +  STUFF((SELECT distinct '<li> <a href="OrganizationHierarchy.aspx?ID='+ CONVERT(NVARCHAR(max), DepartmentID)+'">'+ CONVERT(NVARCHAR(max), DepartmentName) +'</a></li>'    from tbl_Department  where  IsHaveParent = 1 AND ParentID = 2 FOR xml path('')), 1 , 1, '') + '</ul>'
        END 

 print  @ID;
print  @str;
```

But the recursive function returns null

Comment: There's no recursive function in this SQL code. There's a very long unreadable `SELECT` though that looks like an attempt to aggregate strings

Comment: What is "recursive fun"? I've never considered recursion to be fun. And out of interest/curiosity, why are you formatting HTML in your SQL code?

Comment: Is there any reason the HTML is generated with *SQL*? Why not generate this on the client? As for the queries themselves, they aren't reqursive. What `GetDep` does is anyone's guess, especially since the results of the query that feeds to it are probamly more than 2 values. `dbo.GetDep` though will be called just once for every row returned from `tbl_Department`. Its results though will always be the *same* as it doesn't depend on the `tbl_Department` row, just the first row it receives from its inner query

Comment: when building it as a string and  just render it in the repeater,getDep its the function calling them self(recursive) when the dep have a parent

Comment: @MayAbuGhazaleh please don't break the query formatting after someone went to the trouble of cleaning it up so others can understand what's going on, and what's wrong. What's wrong is that there's no recursion and `dbo.GetDep` is essentially a single call that returns a single value

Comment: @MayAbuGhazaleh use a repeater control then, not SQL

Comment: @MayAbuGhazaleh in any case, there's no recursion. `dbo.GetDep((select DepartmentID  from tbl_Department  where  ParentID= @ID))` is essetinally a single call that returns the same thing always. It's equivalent to calling `select @deptID=DepartmentID  from tbl_Department  where  ParentID= @ID; select @dep=dbo.GetDep(@depID)` and using that single `@dep` value in the query

Answer (score 0):

the correct it

ALTER FUNCTION dbo.getSubDep
(
    @ID as integer
)
RETURNS nvarchar(MAX)

AS

BEGIN

```
 Declare @str nvarchar(MAX) ;
 DEclare @xxx integer ;
 Declare @DepID  integer ; 

 set @DepID =  (select count(DepartmentID)  from tbl_Department  where ParentID = @ID )

 IF (@DepID > 0)
      BEGIN
            set @xxx = (select DepartmentID from  tbl_Department  where   tbl_Department.ParentID = @ID);
            set  @str = '<ul class="navbar-mobile-sub__list list-unstyled js-sub-list">' + STUFF((SELECT distinct   ' <li> <a href="OrganizationHierarchy.aspx?ID='+ CONVERT(NVARCHAR(max), DepartmentName)+'">'+ CONVERT(NVARCHAR(max), DepartmentName) +'</a>'   from tbl_Department  where   tbl_Department.DepartmentID =@ID FOR xml path('')), 1 , 1, '') +  dbo.getSubDep(@xxx)+'</li>' + '</ul>'
      END
  ELSE 
      BEGIN
            set  @str =  '<ul class="navbar-mobile-sub__list list-unstyled js-sub-list">' + STUFF((SELECT distinct   ' <li> <a href="OrganizationHierarchy.aspx?ID='+  CONVERT(NVARCHAR(max), DepartmentName)+'">'+ CONVERT(NVARCHAR(max), DepartmentName) +'</a>' +'</li>'  from tbl_Department  where   tbl_Department.DepartmentID =@ID FOR xml path('')), 1 , 1, '')  + '</ul>'
      END 

RETURN  @str

END
```

GO